# Using a different manifestPlaceholder for each Build Variant

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I will start by saying that I am very new to Gradle, so I apologize if this has already been answered.

I'm working on an Android application that uses an API key to access a 3rd party tool.  A different API key needs to be used depending on both the **flavor** and **build type** of the app.

Here is a basic outline of what I'm trying to do:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"DEBUG_KEY" ]
    }

    buildTypes{
        debug{
            // Some debug setup
        }
        release{
            // Some release setup
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        // List of flavor options
    }
    productFlavors.all{ flavor->
        if (flavor.name.equals("someFlavor")) {
            if (buildType.equals("release")) {
                manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"RELEASE_KEY_1" ]
            } else {
                manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"DEBUG_KEY" ]
            }
        } else {
            if (buildType.equals("release")) {
                manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"RELEASE_KEY_2" ]
            } else {
                manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"DEBUG_KEY" ]
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

So far the `manifestPlaceholders` statement is working in a very simple case, but I don't know how to reference the **buildType** from within the **productFlavors** block so that I can use it as a conditional.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would guess that you are referring to Fabric ApiKey? :) I just spent hours trying to do it in a similar way with the placeholders and specifying the ApiKey in the gradle file although it does not seem possible as of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1`. It is possible to specify a placeholder for a specific flavor but not for a flavor AND buildType.

Just to correct your syntax, the way you would have to do it (*if it was possible*) would be something like that but manifestPlaceholders are unknown to variants.

```
applicationVariants.all{ variant->
    if (variant.productFlavors.get(0).name.equals("someFlavor")) {
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals("release")) {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"RELEASE_KEY_1" ]
        } else {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"DEBUG_KEY" ]
        }
    } else {
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals("release")) {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"RELEASE_KEY_2" ]
        } else {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"DEBUG_KEY" ]
        }    
    }
}
```

What you actually need to do is to keep the key in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and handle it with multiple manifest file

**src/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">    
    <application>    
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="DEBUG_KEY" tools:replace="android:value"/>
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

**src/someFlavorRelease/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">    
    <application>    
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="RELEASE_KEY_1" tools:replace="android:value"/>
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

**src/someOtherFlavorRelease/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">    
    <application>    
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="RELEASE_KEY_2" tools:replace="android:value"/>
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

The manifestMerger will handle the replacement and you will end up with the proper key in every scenario. I just implemented it successfully. I just hope you were really referring to the Fabric key! :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your post!  I actually found a different way to do it because of the somewhat unique way that my app is structured, but I do think that yours is probably the correct way to do things.  I am familiar with Fabric, but unfortunately this was for integrating [Localytics](http://www.localytics.com/), a pretty nice analytics platform.  Thanks again for the post! :)

Comment: @Stoph would you mind sharing the way you did it? I'm also looking for a way to deal with this for localytics

Comment: @NelsonRamirez - I actually ended up handing this task off to another developer and, looking at the code now, it doesn't look like they had any more success than I did.  It looks like they went to just using a debug and release key and setting the manifestPlaceholder in the debug/release buildTypes.  I'm sorry that I don't have a better answer.

Comment: You can use `variant.mergedFlavor.manifestPlaceholders =` to update the values without needing to create a `AndroidManifest.xml` for each variant as @Morten Holmgaard answer suggests.

Comment: Could not set unknown property 'manifestPlaceholders' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

Comment: you don't need duplication, check the link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65657119/9315431

Answer (score 51):

You may set manifestPlaceholders inside applicationVariants by accessing mergedFlavor for specific applicationVariant.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def mergedFlavor = variant.getMergedFlavor()
    mergedFlavor.manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageId: "myPackageExample"]
}
```

If you're using the Kotlin DSL, you should use something like this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { // don't put 'variant ->' here or you'll get the 'all' extension function
    // no need to define 'mergedFlavor' because 'this' _is_ the variant so 'mergedFlavor' is already available.
    mergedFlavor.manifestPlaceholders = ...
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it allows you to read properties files (which should contain your keys) in your gradle config which should not be checked into SCM, and then set the key in the manifest placeholder.  By putting the keys into resource files you expose them to anyone who accesses your repo.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. In order to tell variants apart you can do: ```android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def mergedFlavor = variant.getMergedFlavor()
    if (variant.buildType.name.equals("debug") && variant.flavorName.equals("demo")) {
        mergedFlavor.manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageId: "myPackage1"]
    }
}```

Comment: Having trouble getting this to work with `connected` tests. Works fine for everything else

Answer (score 10):

I found this great solution in https://azabost.com/android-manifest-placeholders/

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            manifestPlaceholders.screenOrientation = "portrait"
        }
        debug {...}
    }
}
```

or

```
android {
    ...
    flavorDimensions "features"

    productFlavors {

    paid {
        dimension "features"
        manifestPlaceholders.hostName = "www.paid-example.com"
    }
    free {
        dimension "features"
        manifestPlaceholders.hostName = "www.free-example.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Similarly to the accepted answer, you could do it with string resources, if you didn't want to duplicate your manifests.

For example, if you had two flavors (flavor1 and flavor2)
You'd end up w/ the following source sets.

```
app/
  src/
    main/
      res/
         values/strings.xml
    flavor1Release/
      res/
         values/strings.xml
    flavor1Debug/
      res/
         values/strings.xml

    flavor2Release/
       res/
         values/strings.xml
    flavor2Debug/
       res/
         values/strings.xml
```

You could then just use a string resource for your key value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">    
    <application>    
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="@string/apiKey" tools:replace="android:value"/>
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

One further optimization to keep all your keys in one place is to define them all in strings.xml in your main source set. and then have the flavor/build source sets reference those.

for example:

```
<resources>
    <string name="flavor1ReleaseKey">flavor1ReleaseKey</string>
    <string name="flavor1DebugKey">flavor1DebugKey</string>
    <string name="flavor2ReleaseKey">flavor2ReleaseKey</string>
    <string name="flavor2DebugKey">flavor2DebugKey</string>
</resources>
```

then in each of your flavor/build sourceSets, you just reference those keys.

flavor1Release/res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
     <string name="apiKey">@string/flavor1ReleaseKey</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: This looks like something that could work for us.  Thanks for the new answer!

Comment: This didnt work as it was throwing `Crashlytics Developer Tools error`

Comment: you don't need duplication, check the link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65657119/9315431

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need a manifestPlaceHolder to read that value in your Java code, right? If this is the case, you can already read the FLAVOR name in your generated BuildConfig.java. For example, if you define a flavor whose name is *smartphone* you can access that value using BuildConfig.FLAVOR String; then in your code you can use a simple `if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("smartphone"))...`

But maybe you need to read a sort of configuration of your app, an apiKey. In that case, the best way to go is to create a Class or a string resource for every flavor; this is the [link](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) for you.

Comment: This isn't _exactly_ what I'm trying to do, but the note about being able to access things in your **BuildConfig.java** is helpful.  I might be able to use that to accomplish what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: So, can you explain exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: My understanding is that Gradle will create one Build Variant for each Build Type / Product Flavor combination.  I just want a way to check the Built Type within the `productFlavor` block so that I can determine which hard-coded string API key to use for my manifestPlaceholder.

I'm not sure how much more clear that was, haha, so let me know if that still doesn't make sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Instead of hard coding your api key inside the script, you can hard code it inside your code. You can define an apiKey for every flavor or variant you need. Read this [guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) - section **Add additional source directories for each flavor**. The example talks about different Activities for different flavors, but you can  apply the same example in order to have different resources or different classes and even different manifest files. Hope it can help.

Comment: I know we're already doing something like that for other files, so I can probably piggy-back on that to accomplish what I need.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have not had a chance to implement your suggestion yet, so I don't know if it's the correct one or not.  I still believe that it may work, though, so if you edit your main response to either include or reference your later comment then I will accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What i did is copied current `AndroidManifest.xml` into `app/src/debug`

and changed the key there debug Manifest :

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:value="@string/crashlytics_debug" />
```

`app/src/main` Manifest is like :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
        android:value="@string/crashlytics_live" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need duplicate files
Build.gradle

```
productFlavors {
    prod {
        applicationId "com.example.prod"
        dimension "mode"
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"some String"]
    }
    dev {
        applicationId "com.example.dev"
        dimension "mode"
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"some String"]
    }
```

Manifiest use "${hostName}". Example below

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="${hostName}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @Eric's post, for AGP version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.x`, this code snippet

```
applicationVariants.all{ variant->
    if (variant.productFlavors.get(0).name.equals("someFlavor")) {
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals("release")) {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"RELEASE_KEY_1" ]
        } else {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"DEBUG_KEY" ]
        }
    } else {
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals("release")) {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"RELEASE_KEY_2" ]
        } else {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ apiKey:"DEBUG_KEY" ]
        }    
    }
}
```

should be updated to

```
androidComponents {
    onVariants(selector().withBuildType("debug")) {
        manifestPlaceholders.apiKey = "DEBUG_KEY"
    }

    onVariants(selector().withBuildType("release")) {
        if(flavorName.equals("someFlavor")) 
            manifestPlaceholders.apiKey = "RELEASE_KEY_1"
        else 
            manifestPlaceholders.apiKey = "RELEASE_KEY_2"
    }
}
```