# Set value in manifestPlaceholders to applicationId

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, build.gradle

I am trying to configure some SDK inside application and I am facing this gradle problem, that just gives me a headache. What I have to do is set below value

```
manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "$applicationId"]
```

to be something like `com.flavorA.debug` for debug builds and honestly I have no idea how am I supposed to set this. If I put this section to `defaultConfig` then I get null inside my manifest file. If I put it to `productFlavors` section then I only get com.flavorA, so I'm missing buildType suffix.

I was also trying different things like

```
applicationVariants.each{ variant->
    manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "test"]
}
```

but above doesn't even change the name to test, not mentioning other things.

How am I supposed to solve this with gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need manifestPlaceHolders or the applicationVariants block to achieve this. The applicationId and the package name in the manifest is decoupled, so you simply write:

```
productFlavors {
   pro {
       applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.pro"
   }
   free {
       applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.free"
   }
}
```

and if you want to change it for the build type:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
```

More details here:

[applicationid-vs-packagename](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename)

Comment: I actually need to set it in manifestPlaceholders, since it is required to be set by that SDK which I am trying to use...

Comment: It seems you want to change the applicationId in Gradle. With manifestPlaceHolders you can change tag values in your manifest from Gradle. Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/cdsap/19e277b8597b8b39ebc0

Comment: Or if you want to use the applicationId as the manifest package name, use: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="${manifestApplicationId}" >                                                                       and then                                                                                                             manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "$applicationId" for each flavor]

Comment: As for first example - I have seen it, but when I use $applicationId in `flavor` section, then I am getting `com.flavorA` instead of `com.flavorA.debug`

Comment: Then set applicationIdSuffix '.debug' for debug build type.

Comment: I am setting `applicationIdSuffix` in `buildType` section - the problem is that $applicationId inside `flavor` section is not returning it with suffix

Comment: Have you tried manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "$applicationId" + "$applicationIdSuffix"] or similar?

Comment: Well I've just tried it and as a result I got `com.flavorAnull`, so it seems that applicationIdSuffix is not accessible from flavor section.

Comment: You can't use it directly, but you can set a variable and then use it to set both the applicationId and the manifestPlaceHolder.

Comment: How can I set this variable from buildType?

Comment: I could not get it working. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461267/using-a-different-manifestplaceholder-for-each-build-variant