# Android Studio - Assigning multiple value to ManifestPlaceholders in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I have two environment of my project one **Prod** another one is **Staging**. So whenever I have to build any of the environment, I have to change multiple keys like map key, label name and other things in manifest. So I have searched and find out some of the solutions and **manifestPlaceholders** is one of them.

Now what I want to do is to assign multiple value in **manifestPlaceholders**. So can I put multiple values in it and yes then how to put multiple values in it. Here is the code for the **manifestPlaceholders**

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ google_map_key:"your_dev_key"]
    }
    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ google_map_key:"prod_key"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have solved my problem as below code by adding multiple **manifestPlaceholders** values. Added this to my module `build.gradle`.

```
productFlavors {
        staging {
            applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            manifestPlaceholders = [ google_map_key:"xxxxxxxxxx", app_label_name:"xxxxxxx"]
            buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"xxxxxxxxxx"'
        }
        prod {
            applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            manifestPlaceholders = [ google_map_key:"xxxxxxxxxx", app_label_name:"xxxxxxx"]
            buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"xxxxxxxxxx"'
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
You can use resValue also as `Emanuel Moecklin` suggested in comments.

```
productFlavors {
            staging {
                applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxx"
                manifestPlaceholders = [ google_map_key:"xxxxxxxxxx", app_label_name:"xxxxxxx"]
                buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"xxxxxxxxxx"'
                resValue "string", "base_url", "xxxxxxxxxx"
            }
            prod {
                applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxx"
                manifestPlaceholders = [ google_map_key:"xxxxxxxxxx", app_label_name:"xxxxxxx"]
                buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"xxxxxxxxxx"'
                resValue "string", "base_url", "xxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is usually the preferred solution but I just tripped over an incredible annoying issue. If the place holder value is a number (like 15762790467376475) Gradle converts it to a Float and not a String in which case the value in the manifest would be something like 1.57627904E15). Using resValue instead of the manifestPlaceholders solves this issue.

Comment: But if you have manifestPlaceholders[xy]= in your debug build type you will be overwriting it using manifestPlaceholders =, right? so I suppose it is bette to use manifestPlaceholders[xy]=

Answer (score 28):

You can easily set/change multiple manifestPlaceholders values. You can either define all values at once, as in your answer, or one by one.

```
defaultConfig {
    // initialize more values
    manifestPlaceholders = [ google_map_key:"xxxxxxxxxx", app_label_name:"xxxxxxx"]
    // or this way
    manifestPlaceholders.google_map_key = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    manifestPlaceholders.app_label_name = "xxxxxxxxxx"
}

productFlavors {
    staging {
    }
    prod {
        // use some different value for prod
        manifestPlaceholders.google_map_key = "yyyyyyyyyy"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have mentioned for both build Types and flavors

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        resValue "string", "google_maps_key", "release google map key"
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        resValue "string", "google_maps_key", "debug google map key"
    }
}
productFlavors {
    alpha {
        applicationId = "com.example.alpha"
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'alphaapp'
        resValue "string", "maps_api_key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
    beta {
        applicationId = "com.example.beta"
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'betaapp'
        resValue "string", "maps_api_key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I don't know about that

Comment: It can be done, just write `manifestPlaceholders = [key: "@string/value"]`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36554080/3997741

Answer (score 0):

I could not use the suggested approaches in other answers because gradle seems to have changed the type of `manifestPlaceholders` to **val mutablemap** in a recent release.

This was the only fix that worked for me:

```
manifestPlaceholders["key"] = "value0"
manifestPlaceholders["key"] = "value1"
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, we can set manifestPlaceholders key values using the following ways,

1. select File > Project Strucutre
2. Add environment

- 2-1. select Flavors tab
- 2-2. Add flavor dimension and name for dimension ex."env"
- 2-3. Add product flavor an name product ex. "prod"

3. Add manifestPlaceHolder keys

- 3-1. Select the above product
- 3-2. Add key in Manifest Placeholders list

4. press OK

build.gradle file is automatic updated after press the buttton