# Can Manifest value depend on build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on a multi flavoured product. I want to be able to disable and enable components in the manifest per flavour. I've been able to create such a dependency from bool.xml file to the AndroidManifest.xml in the following way:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.SpecialActivity"
    android:enabled="@bool/is_activity_enabled_in_manifest"/>
```

Can I create the same dependency from the build.gradle to the AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Manifest Placeholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables.html).

Basically, you specify variable in gradle file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"www.example.com"]
    }
    ...
}
```

And then refer to them from `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter ... >
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="${hostName}" ... />
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

In your case this may be applied:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ isActivityEnabled:"true" ]
    }

    buildTypes{
        debug{
            // Some debug setup
        }
        release{
            // Some release setup
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        // List of flavor options
    }
    productFlavors.all{ flavor->
        if (flavor.name.equals("someFlavor")) {
            if (buildType.equals("release")) {
                manifestPlaceholders = [ isActivityEnabled:"false" ]
            } else {
                manifestPlaceholders = [ isActivityEnabled:"false" ]
            }
        } else {
            if (buildType.equals("release")) {
                manifestPlaceholders = [ isActivityEnabled:"true" ]
            } else {
                manifestPlaceholders = [ isActivityEnabled:"true" ]
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

The snippet above is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461267/using-a-different-manifestplaceholder-for-each-build-variant) question.