# Gradle always take the values from the buildType inside the last flavor

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, groovy

In the company where I work we use a lot of flavors in our internal and external projects. Plus 2 or 3 build types too (dev, prod and qa) and sometimes we need to changes specific variables on an specific buildType inside the flavor.

Here is where the problem appears, when I have more that one flavor the Groovy always take the configurations of the last buildType.

Example:

**First of all I define the new buildTypes:**

```
android {
...
 buildTypes {
        development {
            initWith debug
        }
        production {
            initWith release
        }
    }
...
}
```

**Then I define the flavors with the specific buildType changes:**

```
productFlavors {
     mcDonalds {
           ...
            buildTypes {
                development {
                    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "4b77f560-26f3-420d-b438-d7aeb9912d4d",
                                            onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
                }
                production {
                    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "6b77f560-26f3-420d-b438-d7aeb9912d33",
                                            onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
                }
            }
        }
        burgerKing {
           ...
            buildTypes {
                development {
                    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "8b77f560-26f3-420d-b438-d7aeb9912d44",
                                            onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
                }
                production {
                    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "0b77f560-26f3-420d-b438-d7aeb9912456",
                                            onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Regardless of the flavor I choose to build, the gradle will always take the values from the last flavor and when I send a push notification to the mcDonalds users all the burgerKing users will receive ads about the big mac.

Google [told](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71737895) that it's intended and it won't happen if I use build.gradle.ktl. I don't understand how they can say that this is intended. For me it is a Groovy problem, this is a bug and more people are reporting the same issue on the issue tracker.

Which workaround do you suggest?

**Please do not advise me to use another dimension,it would not work because the configurations changes in every flavor/buildType and I think it is ridiculous about the number of build variants:**

- mcDonaldsDevelopmentDebug
- mcDonaldsDevelopmentRelease
- mcDonaldsProductionDebug
- mcDonaldsProductionRelease
- burgerKingDevelopmentDebug
- burgerKingDevelopmentRelease
- burgerKingProductionDebug
- burgerKingProductionRelease

**All I need is something like this:**

- mcDonaldsDevelopment
- mcDonaldsProduction
- burgerKingDevelopment
- burgerKingProduction

Comment: Does the bug you found occur if you try this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32503193/794088 (also,  now I'm hungry)

Comment: Yes, works. But sometimes we have a lot of configurations for each build type and flavor combination and we need to put everything there =\

Comment: Fair point, this simpler approach takes advantage of resource folders and kinda aligns to your intended needs to set the values in the manifest : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36554080/794088

Answer (score 0):

You can have work arounds like: defining string values at the build time which you can reference in any part of the code. Here is an example that may help you or anybody else

```
 buildTypes {
    production {
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    development {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}

productFlavors {
    mcDonalds {
        resValue "string", "key1", "value1"
        resValue "string", "key2", "value2"
    }
    burgerKing {
        resValue "string", "key1", "value1"
        resValue "string", "key2", "value2"
    }
```

}

This will create the following build variants with different configs

1. mcDonaldsDevelopment
2. mcDonaldsProduction
3. burgerKingDevelopment
4. burgerKingProduction

also in your code you can check if you are production of development using the following

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
       //select string for development (key1)
    } else {
       //select string for production (key2)
    }
```