# How set app-linking for a specific build flavor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-build-flavors, android-app-links

I am creating an app with two main flavors, calling it from now on **FlavorA** and **FlavorB**. Each of these flavors has different manifest files, and they have their own Activity (I am working with a single-activity strategy). I have read the following documentations.

[App links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links)

[Deep linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

[App link indexing](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing), which has the most relation with what I have an issue with.

I use **App Links Assistant** from the **Tools** menu, and I am stuck in one of the steps (choosing activity). The issue is that **Android Studio** cannot find the activity that is not defined inside the default manifest file (the activity is defined inside FlavorA's manifest). As a result of this problem, I cannot go to the next step and get the **assetlinks.json** file. I have searched and have not found anything near my question so far. Am I missing a concept, or is there another way of solving this issue?

Comment: @HeshamMorsy sadly, not yet.

Comment: try this answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/52706497/7779496